# Matplotlib Fill_between not working with two curves and 'where' condition

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tildelist = [0.38878, 0.9275000000000001, 1.0493000000000001, 0.7799400000000001, 0.21630000000000005, 0.21630000000000005, 0.9074800000000002, 2.26002, 1.0837400000000001, 0.21630000000000005, 0.21630000000000005, 0.6433, 0.9429000000000001, 0.27622, 0.23996000000000003, 0.6216000000000002, 0.68894, 0.34230000000000005, 0.21630000000000005, 0.47656000000000004, 0.66556, 1.0437, 0.3661, 0.3346, 0.5712, 0.8986600000000002, 0.74746, 0.31094, 0.5712, 0.5661600000000001, 1.3006000000000002, 0.7340199999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 2.5052098332176604, 5.061356833449, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.64234, 1.4148400000000003, 0.9455600000000002, 0.8230599999999999, 1.5153600000000003, 0.5336799999999999, 0.5082, 0.57232, 1.12322, 1.4065800000000002, 0.5368999999999999, 0.21630000000000005, 0.3465000000000001, 0.8829800000000001, 1.8379200000000002, 1.7056200000000001, 1.05252, 1.2306, 0.99176, 1.46076, 1.4128800000000001, 0.8652, 0.9966599999999999, 1.51438, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 2.6159, 3.1127600000000006, 2.7106800000000004, 2.6951400000000003, 4.0, 3.157, 2.1578199999999996, 1.9651800000000001, 1.06834, 1.69694, 1.2080600000000004, 0.8575000000000002]
pvlist = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0024485703275, 0.014189322872999998, 0.017274831464, 0.032399218874, 0.0437174946395, 0.054832859515499995, 0.08097311923249999, 0.14823322805499997, 0.183033049771, 0.3825400623385, 0.40805960146049997, 0.406044572373, 0.4546157846779999, 0.62414554279, 0.8040121546764999, 0.8566804419469998, 0.6471686383579999, 0.8845809490925, 0.883082102771, 0.43601875181149996, 1.0613568334489998, 1.1202136575354997, 1.1654046590229998, 1.2553348183145, 1.1136954158, 1.2222314657959998, 0.9697016623525, 1.2105366156069997, 1.3544616657385002, 0.5278753574214999, 1.353652237894, 1.4534492240674999, 0.6305305066884999, 0.9014175082879999, 0.5823572566129999, 1.0245447414455, 0.7280179826699998, 1.3126664895629998, 1.4048295308685, 1.4523198122069998, 1.2656314751189999, 1.2292708477774998, 1.143669808523, 1.1794532539404998, 0.9664060134575, 0.5818133189604999, 0.4612700229225, 0.8277498967979998, 0.7675148025655, 0.748532423232, 0.7318194628745, 0.5013466543799999, 0.39813316088149997, 0.23136454722699998, 0.1346367369215, 0.17184841006849996, 0.2261439741605, 0.377514939593, 0.302599843469, 0.107099320042, 0.09699960205649999, 0.08806879891699998, 0.045631237310999995, 0.025037315616499998, 0.009905696702, 0.007973754937499999, 0.003431330859, 0.001140702563, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
fixed_time_list = range(96)

resultimg, result = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
images, = result.plot(tildelist, linestyle='-', color='red')
images, = result.plot(pvlist, linestyle='-', color='green')

result.fill_between(fixed_time_list, pvlist, 0, where=pvlist<tildelist, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)

plt.ylabel('Energy value (kW)')
plt.xlabel('Time instant')
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=96)
plt.grid(True)
resultimg = plt.savefig('stackoverflow_example.png', dpi=200) 

plt.close(resultimg)
```

That produces this output:
[image]

Now, what I actually want to obtain (see the where condition) is the area between the x axis and pvlist (the green line) filled, BUT ONLY in the areas where the curve is under tildelist (the red line). It seems like the where condition is not being considered.
Moreover, if I invert the condition (pvlist>tildelist), it actually works! But that's not what I want to obtain.

I also tried to convert the lists into numpy arrays, as suggested to similar questions, but it did not work.

Any help is appreciated. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) for `fill_between`:

> `where` array of bool (length N), optional, default: None
>
> Define where to exclude some horizontal regions from being filled. The 
>      filled regions are defined by the coordinates x[where]

So two things are important here, first your comparison of the lists just returns a single boolean value:

```py
print(pvlist < tildelist)
# True
```

As you suggested one option is to use `numpy` arrays:

```py
tildelist = np.array(tildelist)
pvlist = np.array(pvlist)
print(pvlist < tildelist)
# [ True  ... True False False False  True ... True False False True ...]
```

For me this works and produces the following plots, left `pvlist<tildelist` and right `pvlist>tildelist`:

[image: fillbetween]
[image: fillbetween]

The second thing is that `where` defines where to **exclude some horizontal regions from being filled**.

If you want:

> the area between the x axis and pvlist (the green line) filled, BUT ONLY in the areas where the curve is under tildelist (the red line)

You don't want some horizontal sub regions to be excluded but rather you want to exclude some vertical sub regions.
In other words you want to fill the area between the x axis and a new array which is defined as the minimum of the two curves:

```
pvlist_min = np.min(np.vstack([tildelist, pvlist]), axis=0)
result.fill_between(fixed_time_list, pvlist_min, 0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

[image: fillbetween]

## EDIT

One could add interpolation, because `fill_between` works only point wise so the contours are not filled exactly. By first interpolating the two curves linearly and then calculating the minimum the 
result follows the curves more closely:

```py
def get_x_substeps(x, n_substeps):
    x_steps = np.diff(x, axis=-1) / n_substeps
    delta = np.arange(n_substeps) * x_steps[..., np.newaxis]
    x_ss = (x[:-1, np.newaxis] + delta).flatten()
    x_ss = np.hstack([x_ss, x[-1]])
    return x_ss

n_substeps = 10
tildelist = get_x_substeps(x=tildelist, n_substeps=n_substeps)
pvlist = get_x_substeps(x=pvlist, n_substeps=n_substeps)
fixed_time_list = get_x_substeps(x=fixed_time_list, n_substeps=n_substeps)

pvlist_min = np.min(np.vstack([tildelist, pvlist]), axis=0)

result.fill_between(fixed_time_list, pvlist_min, 0, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

[image: fillbetween]

Comment: What you said is correct. The problem is that I want ALL the area between the green line colored, not just some "strips" as shown in the first picture you produced.
I'm trying some other approaches but I still haven't found a solution that exactly works as I want it to. I'll update my question if I find something relevant.

Comment: I actually reached your same conclusion. Using interpolation is the best solution: the reason is indeed the fact that, considering the condition (where, that returns a Boolean) and the time steps, it is only logical that matplotlib.fill_between behaves so. Thank you for the extensive answer, it was definitely helpful.